# How can I sync the profile picture of my contacts to my online Live.com account?

Tags: sync, contacts, people-hub

I am trying to get the most out of the People Hub. I have spent a lot of time linking profiles and adding pictures, but I don't see the profile pictures in my Live Account on the web. All I can see are the pictures from my Facebook account.

How can I sync my contacts list with photos?

Answer (score 5):

I believe you mean that photos you manually add to contacts stored in your Live account are not shown in your contacts online?

What you need to do first is make sure that the photos are associated with the contact entry on the Live account that you are looking at online. If the photo is associated with a contact stored in, for instance, Google, while it will display on your phone, it will not on the web.

Secondly, after you update your contacts on your phone, you need to make sure that it has performed a sync operation with the web. If you have your account synchronization settings set to only perform syncs at time intervals or manually, you will have to do a manual sync to update the contacts on the web. To do this you'll have to open up the email associated with the account and click the sync button. After it is done, you should see the photos on the web as well.

**EDIT**

After getting on my own computer and checking my contacts page on [the website](http://www.live.com/), I can see for myself that the same problem described occurs for me. I take this to mean that Microsoft simply hasn't implemented this feature, yet. Which is a rather odd ommission. However, as Windows Phone is a relatively new phone OS, this sometimes happens.

Comment: I would be surprised if Microsoft doesn't update this when they rebrand the Live website.  Have you checked if the photo is applied to the server-side contact entry when using the Windows 8 People app?  I have deleted my VM so I cannot test myself (I'm waiting for the Release Preview).

Comment: Thank you for this explanning. I checked every option you describe. But it does not solve the problem. All photo is assotiated with windows live accounts. All changes in text information appears on the web. Photo does not sync whatever.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Checking on my own account (now that I'm on a computer), I see the problem you're describing. I think that this may be a case of "Microsoft didn't implement this yet".

Comment: If it is as you say I will be wait it so much.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Microsoft has updated Hotmail Contacts to Outlook People, it's disappointing to see that there is no support for adding photos to contacts and they do not sync from your Windows Phone.

The only way Outlook People contacts have photographs is from their Windows Live Messenger, Twitter, Facebook or LinkedIn accounts (it does not seem to be pulling them from linked Google accounts and I am not sure about Flickr).  You cannot add your own, like you can on your phone.

However, I have noticed that contacts on my phone that are on my Office 365 Exchange account that I have added my own photo *do* sync to the server, and contact photos that I add within Outlook appear on my phone.  Photos are also added automatically from both Facebook and LinkedIn (you can specify which overrides the other when both are available) and that is overridden by any photo you add yourself.